# create include dependency graph for non-header files

Tags: file, design-patterns, header, doxygen

I try to create an include graph with doxygen v1.8.9.1. In my project I have .c and .h files. But also other file extensions (e.g. .abc) that could have an include statement like

```
#include "common.h"
```

So they can be seen like normal headers. I have added ".abc" in the FILE_PATTERNS as "*.abc". But it is ignoring them and does not parse them. Any help?

Comment: Doxygen versiion 1.8.9.1 is quite old, January 4 2015, the current doxygen version is 1.9.8 so I would certainly advise to update. Furthermore we at least need the settings you used that differ from the default doxygen settings (in the newer versions of doygen the result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`). What is your setting of `INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS`?